# Android Map Center on location only within a certain radius

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am developing a Farmers Market app.  I am having a little trouble getting the map set up just right.  I would like the map to

- zoom to a certain area if the user is not at the market
- When a user is at the market, zoom to their location

The way it seems to work now is, it always zooms to the same spot every time you open the app.  Even if I am at the market.

Any advice would be appreciated.

I have attached my locationmanager from the maps.java file in my project.  I can post the whole java file if that is helpful.

```html
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService
                (Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation
                (LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
        Location centLocation = new Location("");
        centLocation.setLongitude(43.074691);
        centLocation.setLatitude(-89.384152);
        if(location != null) {
            if (location.distanceTo(centLocation) < 250)
                moveToLocation(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 20, 1);
            else
                moveToLocation(new LatLng(43.0746443789058, -89.3860458564343), 20, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            moveToLocation(new LatLng(43.0746443789058, -89.3860458564343), 20, 1);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Comment: That means you can't get current location properly.

Comment: Use the `FusedLocationApi` instead of `LocationManager` to avoid null pointer. Please check [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-location-android) to know how to use it. And [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/getLastLocationUsingGPS-android) is the code for it on my github.